# Referencing variable in Linked List stored in array

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to print variables stored in a linked list of 2 separate classes (a header node containing a string variable and linked nodes containing integer values). I am getting an error that says it cannot find the symbol.

I'm not sure what is going wrong. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Here is the full code:

```
package symboltable;

public class SymbolTable {

    IdentifierHeaderNode[] table = new IdentifierHeaderNode[50];
    IdentifierHeaderNode ptr;

    public SymbolTable(){
        for(int x = 0; x <= 49; x++)

    }

    public void addIdentifier(String info, int lineNumber){
        LineNode ptr;
        LineNode newNode;
        boolean found = false;
        int y = 0;
        int x = 0;

        //Look for Identifier In Array If Found, Add New Node to End
        while(table[y] != null && !found){
            if (table[y].info.equals(info)){
                newNode = new LineNode (lineNumber, null);
                found = true;
            }
            else
                y++;
        }

        //If Identifier Not Found, Create New Identifier and Add Node to End
        IdentifierHeaderNode ident1;
        if(found == false){
            newNode = new LineNode (lineNumber, null);
            ident1 = new IdentifierHeaderNode();
            //Add New Identifier to Table
            while(!found && x <= 50){
                if (table[x] == null){
                    table[x] = ident1;
                    found = true;
                }
                else
                    x = x + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public void print(){

        System.out.println("Symbol Table");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Identifier Name \t Line Appears On");
        int x = 0;
        boolean end = false;
        while(table[x] != null &&!end){
            System.out.print(table[x].info);
            System.out.println(                        table[x].lineNumber);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is where the errors are:

```
if (table[y].info.equals(info))
System.out.print(table[x].info);
System.out.println(                        table[x].lineNumber);
```

Each says "cannot find symbol"
These variables are declared in each of their classes.

IdentifierHeaderNode Class:
    package symboltable;

public class IdentifierHeaderNode {

```
public static String info;
public LineNode first;


public IdentifierHeaderNode(){

}

public IdentifierHeaderNode (String info, LineNode node){
   this.info = info;
   first = node;
}



public String getInfo(){

    return info;
}



}
```

Comment: post the `IdentifierHeaderNode` class.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is in the line `table[x].lineNumber`... I don't see a field called lineNumber in IdentifierHeaderNode, unless you omitted some code.

Also, in `if (table[y].info.equals(info))`, I don't see where you defined `info`, and (although it shouldn't cause an error), since `IdentifierHeaderNode.info` is static, you should access it as that, not as `table[y].info`.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. IdentifierHeaderNode.info is what I'm trying to access here, how would I do so?

Comment: you just access it by typing `IdentifierHeaderNode.info`.  It is a static variable which means that there is only one of it, and it belongs to the whole class.